# jquery text() compare to string

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to compare strings  to jquery text()? I've tried this one but it will not work.

```
var str = 'hello';
var string = $(this).find("text").trim();

if(str == string)
{          
   string.css("visibility", "visible");
}
```

What's wrong with my code? Any idea please? thank you

Comment: Seems fine if there really is a `<text>` node, but `string` is, well, a string, so it won't ever have a `.css` method. You should show your markup & rest of your code.

Comment: I think `var string = $(this).text(").trim();`  then `$(this).css("visibility", "visible");`

Comment: Yes the trim function is important here, first trim then compare string.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use the `text` method you need to actually use it. Using `find("text")` would try fo find a `<text>` element inside the element, and there are no such elements.

Also, use the jQuery `trim` method as the `string.trim` method isn't available in all browsers. Apply the style to the element, not the string:

```
var str = 'hello';
var string = $.trim($(this).text());

if(str == string)
{          
   $(this).css("visibility", "visible");
}
```

Comment: I have <text> node in the element but i dont know wats da problem.

Comment: @LynerKharl: Then you would use `var string = $.trim($(this).find('text').text());`.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you getting any error?

Usually calling .find on something will search for a DOM element. find is not for searching text.

With find("text") you are looking for  elements in the DOM tree. And they don't have .trim() methods associated, so you should be getting an error like *'TypeError: undefined is not a function'*

Maybe what you want to do is the following...

```
var string_elem = $(this),
    str = 'hello',
    string = string_elem.find("text").text().trim();

if(str === string) {
    string_elem.css('visibility', 'visible');
}
```

Also, if you want your string comparison to be case insensitive you should do something like this

```
if(str.toLowerCase() === string.toLowerCase())
```

Comment: Thank you @Danikaze. But it didn't work for me when I apply a .trim(). I tried to alert("worked") when the first condition applies and then alert("failed") when it didnt match but the result will always "failed" even the condition is true. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: I've tried to display the string through "ALERT STRING" and it returns object Object.

Comment: What is **this** in this context? I just assumed it's a DOM element. Is there more than one <text> element inside string_elem?

Comment: There's only one <text> element>

Answer (score 0):

`string` is just a string, so you cannot `.css();`.

and better use some other variable name instead of `string`, this seems to be already reserved one.

try this

```
var str = 'hello';
var string = $(this).find("text").trim();
var string_elem = $(this);
if(str == string){          
   string_elem.css("visibility", "visible");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But it didn't work for me when I apply a .trim(). I tried to alert("worked") when the first condition applies and then alert("failed") when it didnt match but the result will always "failed" even the condition is true. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: I've tried to display the string through "ALERT STRING" and it returns object Object.